# Is there a faster way to reindex grouped dataframes in pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
    Time                ID   Col
0   2023-02-08 06:00:00 1   10.01
1   2023-02-08 06:00:01 1   21.10
2   2023-02-08 06:00:05 1   21.02
3   2023-02-08 06:10:01 2   54.02
4   2023-02-08 06:10:03 2   56.02
5   2023-02-08 06:10:05 2   65.03
```

which can be generated with the code below:

```
from datetime import datetime
data = {'Time': ["2023-02-08 06:00:00","2023-02-08 06:00:01","2023-02-08 06:00:05","2023-02-08 06:10:01","2023-02-08 06:10:03","2023-02-08 06:10:05"],
        'ID': ['1','1','1','2','2','2'],
        'Col': [10.01,21.1,21.02,54.02,56.02,65.03]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

I want to fill in the missing time gaps (filling with zeroes) for every ID. So the output should be this:

```
    Time            ID  Col
2023-02-08 06:00:00 1   10.01
2023-02-08 06:00:01 1   21.10
2023-02-08 06:00:02 0   0.00
2023-02-08 06:00:03 0   0.00
2023-02-08 06:00:04 0   0.00
2023-02-08 06:00:05 1   21.02
2023-02-08 06:10:01 2   54.02
2023-02-08 06:10:02 0   0.00
2023-02-08 06:10:03 2   56.02
2023-02-08 06:10:04 0   0.00
2023-02-08 06:10:05 2   65.03
```

I managed to make it work with this code for a small dataset (~200000 rows) and it took about an hour:

```
filled_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
grouped = df.groupby('ID')
for name, group in grouped:
    idx = pd.date_range(min(group.Time), max(group.Time), freq='S')
    group = group.set_index('Time')
    group = group.reindex(idx).fillna(0)
    filled_dataframe = pd.concat([filled_dataframe,group])
```

Now, my real dataset is around 50 millions rows (and 66 columns) and by some rough estimates it should take days to finish. So the question is: Is there a faster way to achieve this? Maybe ditch the for loop and use a vectorized alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html):

```
out = (df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)
         .resample('S', on='Time').first() # use different method if needed
         .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
         .reset_index('Time')[df.columns]
      )
```

Output:

```
                 Time ID    Col
0 2023-02-08 06:00:00  1  10.01
0 2023-02-08 06:00:01  1  21.10
0 2023-02-08 06:00:02  0   0.00
0 2023-02-08 06:00:03  0   0.00
0 2023-02-08 06:00:04  0   0.00
0 2023-02-08 06:00:05  1  21.02
1 2023-02-08 06:10:01  2  54.02
1 2023-02-08 06:10:02  0   0.00
1 2023-02-08 06:10:03  2  56.02
1 2023-02-08 06:10:04  0   0.00
1 2023-02-08 06:10:05  2  65.03
```

Keeping the ID:

```
out = (df.set_index('ID').groupby('ID')
         .resample('S', on='Time').first() # use different method if needed
         .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
         .reset_index()[df.columns]
      )
```

Output:

```
                  Time ID    Col
0  2023-02-08 06:00:00  1  10.01
1  2023-02-08 06:00:01  1  21.10
2  2023-02-08 06:00:02  1   0.00
3  2023-02-08 06:00:03  1   0.00
4  2023-02-08 06:00:04  1   0.00
5  2023-02-08 06:00:05  1  21.02
6  2023-02-08 06:10:01  2  54.02
7  2023-02-08 06:10:02  2   0.00
8  2023-02-08 06:10:03  2  56.02
9  2023-02-08 06:10:04  2   0.00
10 2023-02-08 06:10:05  2  65.03
```

Comment: Nice! This took around 7 minutes compared to the 75 minutes that mine took! One more question: I would like to set all columns to zero **except** for the 'ID' which I would like to keep. So, I corrected my solution and put ```group['ID'] = name``` in the loop. How would I do that with your code? I tried setting as_index=True but it didn't work.

Comment: See update to keep the ID